# Resize ROI in an image by mantaining original image size

Tags: python, opencv

I have this test image:

[image: src]

What I would like to achieve is to reduce the inside ROI (text region) but mantaining the original image size.

Something like this:

[image: src_dest]

If you compare the two images they have the same dimensions.
Also the ROI should be centered.

I use OpenCv and Python.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resize the roi by half then append to the image, see the code for more information:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("1.png")

print(image.shape)
h = image.shape[0]
w = image.shape[1]

center_x = int(w/2)
center_y = int(h/2)

#get the roi, suppose the roi is in the center of the image
roi = image[center_y-50:center_y+50,center_x-140:center_x+140,:].copy() 
roi_h = roi.shape[0]
roi_w = roi.shape[1]

resize_roi = cv2.resize(roi,(int(roi_w/2),int(roi_h/2)))
print(resize_roi.shape)

#delete the old roi
image[center_y-50:center_y+50,center_x-140:center_x+140,:] = 255

#append the resize_roi
image[center_y-int(50/2):center_y+int(50/2),center_x-int(140/2):center_x+int(140/2),:] = resize_roi

cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.imshow("roi", roi)
cv2.imshow("resize_roi", resize_roi)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The roi

[image]

The resize roi

[image]

The image with resize roi

[image]